# How do I incorporate Stripe with my PHP sign up form?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, stripe-payments

How do I make it so that when a user clicks the "Sign up" button on the form code, to go to the stripe code/button. And, once they have finished that, they continue through the sign up form.

Stripe code:

```
<div id="container">
<?php
  require_once('../stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
  $stripe = array(
    'secret_key'      => 'secretkey',
    'publishable_key' => 'publickey'
    );
  Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <script src="https://button.stripe.com/v1/button.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
        data-amount=53500
        data-description="One Wilde quote"
        data-label="Buy"></script>
    </form>
  <?php
  }
?>
  </div><!-- #container -->
```

Form code:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-signin" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="post">
<legend class="form-signin-heading">Register</legend>
<input class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
<br>
<input class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
<br>
<input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
<br>
<input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
<br>
<input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
<br>
<input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password Again" type="password">
<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="terms" checked="checked" onclick="return false;"> I agree with the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>.</label>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: the usual process = fill form >process form >send to payment gateway. payment gate way takes payment and returns user to url specified and (somehow) notifies you payment was made. where the issue?

Comment: How do I send the user to a special url after they make the payment? Do I have to make my own PHP for that or do I change it somewhere in Stripe.js?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483444/how-do-i-make-my-php-sign-up-form-include-stripe

Comment: every payment gateway i have worked with you tell it what url to return the user to.

Comment: I'm pretty much lost. Do you think you can show me where that would be in here [https://github.com/stripe/wilde-things/tree/master/stripe](https://github.com/stripe/wilde-things/tree/master/stripe) ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're working from some old example code and not from Stripe's documentation. What you're looking for is now called [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout), and they've got some very good documentation for it.

If you're looking for a complete learning experience, they also have a more detailed [PHP integration tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php).

But in a nutshell:

Stripe is a traditional payment processor. It's not PayPal or WorldPay or what have you; the user never leaves your site, and you never code flow control. If you want to redirect the user to a specific page, then that occurs in *your* PHP code just like it always does.

When the user finishes with the Checkout (nee Button) form, Checkout will POST their payment token to the form action you've specified (`index.php` in the code you've posted). That page is responsible for actually billing the user and then redirecting to or displaying whatever content you want to display.